# Plugging my hard drives into a USB hub

Tags: linux, usb, usb-storage, usb-3, usb-hub

This may sound like a silly question, but I'm currently running Linux and have 4 USB drives plugged into the back of my computer.  I was thinking of just getting one USB 3.0 hub and plugging all my drives into the hub instead.  Just wondering, since the drives are mounted by the drives' UUID, will it change because it's plugged into a USB hub?  Or does the hub just pass the drive information through?  I know in Windows it's a no-brainer but is it different for LInux?  I don't have a hub yet, so thought I would ask before I get one.

**Update**

I was wondering if a [hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013OK10YM) like this would be efficient enough to power 4 USB drives without any issues

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any old usb hub should work fine with any modern linux distro. Never had a problem yet. http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-678950.html just a ubuntu post saying about the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

#### A hub will connect multiple drives with Linux and move data, but there are some limitations:

- **Power considerations:**  Make sure it's a powered hub.  Each drive will use most of the power available per port, so you can't power multiple drives from the hub's connection to the computer.

  The link you added to the question is for a hub with high-current charging ports. In general, USB drives that do not have their own power supply should get enough power from a normal USB 3.0 port. Devices designed to use those high-current ports negotiate their power requirements. A USB drive is designed to work on a standard port. The hub should work, but if you aren't using it to charge other devices, you're probably paying for a capability you won't use.
- **Bandwidth considerations:**  If the drives are USB 3.0 mechanical drives, four drives transferring data concurrently would be within the bandwidth of the hub's USB 3.0 connection to the computer.

  Note that a USB 3.0 hub and its PC connection contain separate data paths for USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 devices.  The USB 3.0 devices and USB 2.0 devices each have concurrent access to their own full respective bandwidths, but can't make use of available bandwidth of the other standard.

  If you plug multiple USB 2.0 drives into the hub, they will be competing for the USB 2.0 bandwidth, which is barely adequate for a single slow mechanical drive (which is likely what is inside a USB 2.0 enclosure).  More than one slow USB 2.0 drive will see degraded performance if you use them concurrently.

  Unless you are moving huge files, a drive tends not to be moving data 100% of the time, which reduces the competition for the bandwidth. If access to each drive is only occasional, you might not notice much degradation. But each USB 2.0 drive you add to the hub, that ever gets used concurrently, increases the percentage of time that more than one drive will be trying to move data through the bottleneck of the hub's USB 2.0 path to the PC.

Comment: Each drive is used for each of the 4 vm I have.  2 Are just for backup but 2 are my plex and git server.  I read somewhere that its probably a good idea not to plug more than 2 USB hard drives per hub.  So going by that idea would I be better off getting two USB 3 powered hub and put two drives per hub?

Comment: Would a hub like this one

Comment: Thank you so much your explanation. Two of my usb drives are backups so I can put that together in one hub because the backups are done one after the other.  I can probably put my git and media drives on another one because the git server is going to be used occasionally and media drive is going to be the one that gets used moderately.